# Can't activate virtualenv from python script with shebang

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, shebang

I'm using PythonAnywhere. I've used `virtualenvwrapper` to create an environment where I have the required packages.

When in bash I do:

```
activate virtualenv
python my_subfolder/my_script.py
```

and it works.

However, I want to run this scheduled using PythonAnywhere's feature for scheduling. But when it runs, it reverts (expectedly) to the default Python interpreter.

I'm not so good with paths and navigating, so I tried shebanging in various ways. I know for certain that my venv is in this path:

```
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/my_username/files/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_venv/bin/python
```

I'm omitting the domain of course, but trying to append any of the following parts of the URL to `#!` like so never works:

```
#!user/my_username/files/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_venv/bin/python
```

Please note that the script is in a subfolder `my_subfolder/my_script.py`. I've also `chmod u+x` the Python script. Very confused.

Comment: Try using `/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_venv/bin/python` -- the part at the start is just the URL that you'd use to access it.  The bit starting `/home` is the Linux path to your Python interpreter.

Comment: Um are you actually trying to first "activate" it and then run the script? If these are two different shells, you won't be able to do that because sourcing `activate` will only be relevant for the same shell. Don't activate. Instead, just pass the full path to the python interpreter you want to use to run the script.

Comment: have you solved this problem?